# Trying to get a logged in user's email

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have been stuck on this form months. I am trying to get the email address of the logged in chrome user. I first tried:

```
  chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(userInfo) ) but couldn't get a returned email address.
```

Now I am trying to use the example from the No Idea Blog:
https://noidea.dog/blog/chrome-identity-api

I have copied their code into my background.js. Here is my background.js:

```
chrome.identity.getProfileUserInfo(function(info) { email = info.email; });

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, 
sendResponse) {
    sendResponse( {email: email})
});
```

I have modified the "login button" in my popup.js:

```
   $('#btnLogin').button().click(function () {
    var logged_in_user;
    chrome.extension.sendMessage({}, function(response) {
        logged_in_user = response.email
                });
        console.log("Got user:", logged_in_user);          
    });
```

And here is part of my manifest.json:

```
 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistant": false
 },
 "permissions": [
  "activeTab",
  "identity",
  "identity.email",
  "http://localhost/*.*"
  ],
 "oauth2":{
    "client_id": "koinkhimjmddddjlmfplohggjnnmixxx",
    "scopes": [ "email"]

  }
```

When I run this I get Got user: undefined. What am I doing wrong?